# How to user app_user in the where condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

using v('APP_USER') in where condition is returning to null records

```
select FULL_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS from headcount where EMAIL_ADDRESS = v('APP_USER')
```

Comment: are you executing this query in an apex app or in sql ? For v('APP_USER') to return a value you need to be in a valid apex session.

Comment: I'm executing the query in Apex

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your query. Try this - select v('APP_USER') INTO :P6_NEW FROM DUAL; to see if the issue is really with v('APP_USER').

Comment: `APP_USER` will be uppercase, whereas your table might have lower case or mixed case values in `email_address`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to get the value of APP_USER in an apex session. The preferred way is the bind variable (:APP_USER) but you can you also use the sys_context variable SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER') or the V function (V('APP_USER')). To prove that works I created a report with the following query:

```
WITH app_user_tab AS (SELECT 'bind var' as type, :APP_USER as username FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'context',SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'v', v('APP_USER') FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM app_user_tab
```

And i got 3 identical rows as expected.

Which leads me to believe your problem is not with the app user, but with the value in headcount.email_address. It could be:

- case not matched.
- leading/trailing control characters in the headcount.email_address column

Answer (score 0):

you have to use bind variables in your sql.
V / NV functions are used in compiled code, such as views, packages, and procedures.

[more info are here](https://www.talkapex.com/2011/01/variables-in-apex/)

Comment: V() substitution works fine even in sql queries as well. It need not be a compiled code. Am i wrong?

Comment: in the documentation, it is recommended to NOT use this syntax when referencing items in SQL.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldapp_item.htm#HTMDB25335
but I think you are right it may not be the problem.

Comment: Thanks subhi. I didn't know that. Very nice point. The documentation says using it in SQL might have performance issues. Then better go with bind variable substitution itself.